# How to make an app bar using React & Material-UI like this?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, react-native, material-ui

How do I make an app bar that looks like this: [image]

I can create the top half of the app bar with the search box but I'm having trouble adding the bottom half. This is my code so far:

```
      <AppBar
        style={{backgroundColor: MuiTheme.palette.primary1Color, flexWrap: 'wrap'}}
        showMenuIconButton={false}
        title={explorerSearch}
        titleStyle={MuiTheme.title}
        iconClassNameRight='muidocs-icon-navigation-expand-more'
      >
        <Toolbar>
          <ToolbarGroup>
            {this._getContent()}
          </ToolbarGroup>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
```

This is what the output looks like: [image]

I'd like the "TEXT" to show up in a new line below the search bar. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding to styles `flexDirection: 'column'`?

Just replace the style You got there:

```
style={{backgroundColor: MuiTheme.palette.primary1Color, flexWrap: 'wrap'}}
```

to

```
style={{backgroundColor: MuiTheme.palette.primary1Color, display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column'}}
```