# How to add search bar in AppBar of material-ui?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to implement Search bar in the center of App bar of material-ui. I have tried all possible ways and I have referred this [code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40026643/how-to-make-an-app-bar-using-react-material-ui-like-this) , but can't find a solution for it.

My code snippet is

```
<div>
  <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={muiTheme} class="navbar">
    <AppBar 
     title='Module Name' 
     onTitleClick={handleClick} 
     iconElementRight={<FlatButton label='LogOut' />}
     onClick = {handleclick}
    />
   </MuiThemeProvider>
 </div>
```

It will be helpful if I get any solution for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `children` property to add any node in AppBar, like this:

```
<AppBar
    title="Title"
    children= {
      <input />
    }
/>
```

Use styling on input field, check the working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/4jx88nvy34).

Comment: Sir, adding children renders `input` field on the right side. How to make it in center of the appBar.

Comment: I don't think this works for the @material-ui/core > 1.0, depending on your styles. Adding {flex: 1} to the style of preceding child (e.g. Title) should push the input-field to the right.

Answer (score 1):

you can add a ToolBar contains a Textfield
you can check [documentation](https://material-ui-next.com/demos/app-bar/) ,this is a [Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/2p2ov8315n)

Answer (score 1):

1. Using only Material UI

```js
<AppBar>
    <Toolbar>
        <Input 
            type="search"
            />
    </Toolbar>
</AppBar>
```

You can check the [docs](https://material-ui.com/api/input/#main-content) here.

2. Installing another framework.

> ```
> npm i material-ui-search-bar
> ```

A basic code snippet can be found on the main page.

```js
import SearchBar from "material-ui-search-bar";
// *snip*
    
return (
    <SearchBar
        value={this.state.value}
        onChange={(newValue) => this.setState({ value: newValue })}
        onRequestSearch={() => doSomethingWith(this.state.value)}
    />
    );
```

You can check the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-ui-search-bar) here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<AppBar>
  <Toolbar>
    <InputBase placeholder="Search for products, brands and more" />
  </Toolbar>
</AppBar>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass a prop in the `AppBar` component

```
 <AppBar
    title="Title"
    showSearch= {
      <Toolbar>
        <InputBase placeholder="Search" />
      </Toolbar>
    }
/>
```

You can handle `AppBar` component based on `customName` prop like if you're passing this prop then it should show Search else not.